# I haven't failed an audit in ages - but I just did and now I'm banned

Tags: support, status-completed, review-audits, review-suspension

So I haven't failed a review audit in ages. That being said, I mis-clicked *Approve* and it had a cow and banned me for two days.

> You have failed too many audits

Why am I now unable to complete my daily morning ritual for two days? That means I have to do actual work at work now 5 minutes earlier.

---

More specifically, what constitutes as *Too many audits*? If it's one, then why don't we change the wording?

Comment: Oh, hey, forgot to mention... I was playing around on your computer yesterday and failed like 15 audits in a row...

Comment: :( wai u do dis @YourBoss

Comment: Correction; misclicked [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5253151) apparently.

Comment: @Qix wait, so if you would actually think that you could improve that suggested edit you would not be allowed? What if you would in fact have improved the OP?

Comment: Well, what would have happened if that was an actual question you misclicked? I know it seems silly banning you for 2 days, but the ban is clearly doing it's job in making you think about what you're clicking.

Comment: Happened to me as well, more than once. Especially with the late answers, for some reason...

Comment: -1 for making me think of Justin Timberlake, cry me a river.

Comment: Quix, you are fired! (your ex Boss)

Comment: @JamesHunt, Ofcourse that assumes that the review was a valid audit question in the first place. Far too often, they are not valid.

Comment: The audit results shown in such a way that you cannot identify that it was an audit or not. So you suffered this problem.

Comment: Are you normally passing or skipping any of the obvious audits? I have the feeling that skipping them and then failing one, and having no passed record is bad

Comment: @Qix See the history tab when in review queue to see how often you failed and how often you passed.

Comment: @ouflak: It was a suggested edit review, which is not taken from an existing edit; it’s generated, never makes sense, and is never arguable for the “it looked fine!” case.

Comment: @Palec, I am aware. Like I said, I haven't failed one in ages.

Comment: @JamesHunt Refer to my comment and the review audit; I hit edit, not approve. If I approved something by accident I would make the effort to go back and rollback if it were approved overall. However I did hit edit and thus would have been able to cancel.

Comment: I lifted your ban.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Lifting the ban may make this complaint [status-completed], but I'm still interested to know why only one audit failure triggers a ban.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: It's a fairly serious audit fail, fat-fingered or not.  I would imagine that the threshold is set to 1 occurrence.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So the threshold is dependent on the severity of the failure? I too just fat-fingered a "should be improved" instead of "unsalvageable" in a Triage audit, maybe my 3rd in the last 200 reviews and wound up with a ban.