# Failed an audit and blocked from reviewing

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I was going through the Low Quality review and came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7645687).

The answer, while it could be more detailed, did try to answer the question with a code snippet. Additionally, the answerer included a link to a YouTube video showing a screen cast of something they could try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), a popular debugging tool.

That being said, the code had a few two many indents, so I hit edit to remove them so I could move on. I failed the audit. I'm certain a "Look OK" would have failed it as well.

The answer was deleted as as "spam or offensive," neither of which the original answer was. I'm assuming it somehow was flagged as a spammy link, which holds a higher weight in the audit processing for auto-blocking. Now, I'm blocked for 2 days over, what I believe, was a bad audit.

Comment: It would be incredibly unfortunate if hitting a review ban instantly disqualified a candidate from an election ;)

Comment: No kidding! My first thoughts! I'm like... Okay, I need to look deeper into this in case there is something I'm missing.

Comment: It seems unreasonable that editing fails this audit in particular, it's too vague. It's probably just a poor audit IMO. See also [*"Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168374/244864).

Comment: similar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263058/i-havent-failed-an-audit-in-ages-but-i-just-did-and-now-im-banned

Comment: A screenshot would be nice for those of us who don't have enough rep to see it.